# Relationship between covariance matrix and its determinant

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X=(X_1, X_2,..., X_n)$ be random variables
$$
v_{ij} = cov(X_i, X_j) = E(X_i, X_j) - E(X_i)(X_j)
$$

Show that the det of *v* is zero iff there are $a_1, a_2,..., a_n $ and *b* such that

$$
P(a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 +... + a_nX_n = b) = 1
$$

I'm not sure how to even begin this problem, so any leads would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant is zero if and only if the matrix is singular if and only if there exists $a$ such that 
$$
Ca=0
$$ 
where $C$ is the covariance matrix. The variance of 
$$
y = a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 +... + a_nX_n
$$
is
$$
a^t C a 
$$
which is zero.

So $y$ is almost surely constant and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try computing $\text{Var}(a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\dots+a_nX_n)$. What does it mean if a random variable has zero variance?